# Script to remove multiple databases from HA

Tags: sql-server, high-availability, alwayson

Problem Statement :
We two database server (SQL01 & SQL02). Lets assume SQL01 is my primary server and SQL02 is secondary server. My primary database server contain around 100 databases and SQL02 is connected to SQL01 as the fail over server. For our test we have taken the back up of the physical `mdf` and `ldf` file on the primary server. And after every test we reset the database (replacing the mdf and ldf file with the files after teenter code herest).

Now to make them in sync on the secondary server we are doing manually three steps

1. Remove the databases from HA group from primary server.
2. Drop the database on Secondary server
3. Add them back to HA on primary server.

So for the first step we are doing it from SQL server management studio, Windows application and sometime we are using the following script

```
USE [master]
GO
ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP [PERFAG02]
REMOVE DATABASE [db1];
GO
```

can someone help me with procedure which can remove them in one go. Although I am not expert in database.

Comment: So you want a cursor for all databases that will remove current db from availability group?

Comment: @sepupic yeah, this is the basic idea.